# The Moore Plane's topology

Tags: general-topology

In the definition of the Moore plane $X=L{_1}\cup L{_2}$, where $L{_1}$ is the line $y=0$ and
$L{_2}=X\setminus L{_1}$ , I have a problem. In the Engelsking's book, for each $x\in L{_1}$
neghbourhood of $x$, is the form $U(x,1/i)\cup \{ x \}$ where $U(x,1/i)$ be the set of $X$ inside the circle centered $x$ and radius $1/i$ for i=1,2,..... So, I wonder that whether or not radius is greater than $1$?If it is, how can cover all $X$ with small radius? thanks

Comment: Isn't $1/i$ smaller then $1$? I hope I did not misunderstood your question.

Comment: I mean that, radius can be greater than $1$?

Comment: I see. If $M>1$, $U(x, M)\cup\{x\} = \big(U(x,1) \cup \{x\}\big) \cup B$, where $B$ is the usual open set in $L_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to cover $X$ with basic open nbhds of points of $L_1$: you also have the basic open nbhds of points of $L_2$, which are ordinary Euclidean balls small enough to stay within $L_2$. Specifically, the following collection is a base for $X$:

$$\left\{\{\langle x,0\rangle\}\cup B\left(\left\langle x,\frac1k\right\rangle,\frac1k\right):k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\left\{B(\langle x,y\rangle,\epsilon):y>0\text{ and }0<\epsilon\le y\right\}\;,$$

where for $B(p,r)$ is the usual Euclidean open ball of radius $r$ centred at $p$.

Note that your description of basic open nbhds at points of $L_1$ isn’t actually correct: the ball $U$ is **tangent** to $L_1$ at $x$ and therefore does not have its centre at $x$.

Comment: I think that there is a problem for the neighbourhood of $x\in L_2$,in above.Each singletion can not be open in Euclidean topology.

Comment: @ghb: That’s irrelevant: the topology of the Moore plane **isn’t** the Euclidean topology.

Comment: But, each $x \in L_2$, the neighbourhood of $x$ in Euclidien topology, according to the definition of the Moore plane.

Comment: @ghb: Sorry: I was thinking of a slightly different space that is sometimes called the Moore plane. You’re right: $L_2$ has the Euclidean topology, and I’ll modify my answer accordingly. But I still don’t see what problem you think exists.

Comment: thanks so much for decsription of topology.It is now clear .John's comment also useful for my question.

Comment: @ghb: You’re very welcome.